# how to pass in folder path in urllib rest post call

Tags: python-3.x, rest, post, urllib

have a post call as below:

http://localhost:8086/service/records/bulkimport?overwrite=true&classroom=grade1&dir=C:\Users\temp\classroomRecords\grade1

tried to implement in python3.6 using urllib as below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, URLError, Request
from urllib.parse import urlencode

loadRecordsRestCall = 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/bulkimport'
values = {'overwrite' : 'true',
      'classroom' :  'grade1',
      'dir' : 'C:\\Users\\temp\\classroomRecords\\grade1'}
data = urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = Request(self.loadRecordsRestCall, data)
with urlopen(req) as loadRecordsRestCall:
    print("Status: %s" % loadRecordsResponse.getcode()) 
    print("Response: %s" % loadRecordsResponse.read())
```

But each time it showed error code 500, did a research online, do not want to user external library, if just using urllib, how to make it work.

Below are the error message, does anyone know what is wrong here: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
      response = meth(req, response)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in
         http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _ 
       call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in 
       http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Request failed.

Comment: Have you looked at the error log yet?

Comment: yes, I checked the error log, pasted in the original post too, but still can not figure out what is wrong here, could you suggest something to check here

Comment: That's just the traceback of the client code. Where is the error log of the server?

Comment: Thanks, I am checking now, there are some nullpoint error, the part I don't understand is I tried the full url call with all the three parameters set in Fiddler, it works, but in the python code, not working, means its not service or api prolbrom, must be in the python urllib rest call, not make the rest call right.

Comment: the error in the service seems the folder path is not passed in right, do you have any idea for how should pass in the folder path here

Comment: I have no idea what your server-side code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, and turned out the service side API is requiring query param. so I used formated url string to make the call.